# Calculate Rolling Mean Without Using pd.rolling_mean()

Tags: python, pandas

I know rolling_mean() exists, but this is for a school project so I'm trying to avoid using rolling_mean()

I'm trying to use the following function on a dataframe series

```
def run_mean(array, period):
    ret = np.cumsum(array, dtype=float)
    ret[period:] = ret[period:] - ret[:-period]
    return ret[period - 1:] / period

data['run_mean'] = run_mean(data['ratio'], 150)
```

But I'm getting the error 'ValueError: cannot set using a slice indexer with a different length than the value'.

Using `data['run_mean'] = pd.rolling_mean(raw_data['ratio'],150)` works exactly fine, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill the initial values up to period with `NaN`.

```
def run_mean(array, period):  # Vector
    ret = np.cumsum(array / period, dtype=float)  # First divide by period to avoid overflow.
    ret[period:] = ret[period:] - ret[:-period]
    ret[:period - 1] = np.nan
    return ret 

run_mean(np.array(range(5)), 3)
Out[35]: array([ nan,  nan,   1.,   2.,   3.])
```

Answer (score 1):

To quote [the pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series),

> A key difference between Series and ndarray is that operations between Series automatically align the data based on label. Thus, you can write computations without giving consideration to whether the Series involved have the same labels.

This example should illustrate what's going on:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: import pandas as pd

In [2]: a = pd.Series(np.random.random(5))

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
0    0.740975
1    0.983654
2    0.274207
3    0.427542
4    0.874127
dtype: float64

In [4]: a[2:]
Out[4]: 
2    0.274207
3    0.427542
4    0.874127
dtype: float64

In [5]: a[:-2]
Out[5]: 
0    0.740975
1    0.983654
2    0.274207
dtype: float64

In [6]: a[2:] - a[:-2]
Out[6]: 
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    0.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
dtype: float64

In [7]: a[2:] = _
```

The last statement will produce the `ValueError` you get.

Converting `ret` from a pandas `Series` to a numpy `ndarray` should give you the behaviour you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up the use of `:` in `DataFrame` slicing.

#### Solution

What you want to use is `shift()`

```
def run_mean(array, period):
    ret = np.cumsum(array, dtype=float)
    roll = ret - ret.shift(period).fillna(0)
    return roll[(period - 1):] / period
```

#### Example Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(314)
df = pd.DataFrame((np.random.rand(6, 5) * 10).astype(int), columns=list('ABCDE'))

print df

   A  B  C  D  E
0  9  5  2  7  9
1  8  7  2  9  2
2  7  2  1  3  8
3  2  0  6  5  5
4  6  6  4  3  5
5  4  8  8  1  0
```

Observe

```
print df[:4]

   A  B  C  D  E
0  9  5  2  7  9
1  8  7  2  9  2
2  7  2  1  3  8
3  2  0  6  5  5

print df[:-4]

   A  B  C  D  E
0  9  5  2  7  9
1  8  7  2  9  2
```

These are not the same length.

#### Demonstration

```
          A         B         C         D         E
2  8.000000  4.666667  1.666667  6.333333  6.333333
3  5.666667  3.000000  3.000000  5.666667  5.000000
4  5.000000  2.666667  3.666667  3.666667  6.000000
5  4.000000  4.666667  6.000000  3.000000  3.333333
```